# Does VS2015 automatically include windows SDK header files but not in VS2017?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I have a C++ library originally developed in VS2015 which uses SOCKET from Winsock2 inside Windows SDK 8.1. The solution file is generated from a cmake file, and it builds perfectly fine.
I use the same cmake file to create the solution again in VS2017. However, I can not compile it unless I add #include <WinSock2.h> at the file where SOCKET is being used. It looks like it's not picking up the definition of SOCKET unless I explicitly include the WinSock2.h file. And I don't need to do that in VS2015.

I checked the project properties and they look the same and are both using Windows SDK 8.1. So what is the difference here with VS2015 and VS2017? Does VS2015 automatically include windows SDK header files but not in VS2017?

Comment: This may be because one of your other includes was already including winsock2 for you, but a change in the headers changed this behaviour. These kinds of changes happen, which is why you should generally include all the headers you need.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood what you are saying, but there is really no other header include in that file that includes winsock2. And I don't see it being part of the pre-compiled header neither. Just a reminder that the source code of everything is exactly the same in VS2015 and VS2017, except I need to add #include <winsock2.h> to get VS2017 to compile.

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying, and it seems to be the case. Even my source code stays the same, the dependency libraries for vs2015 and vs2017 are different in my project and an underlying header deep down is different (one includes winsock2 and one doesn't).

Comment: My psychic powers suggest that `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` is defined by default in VS2017.